# java―binary inserts are not copied one to one

Tags: java, io

I have wrote some code to process a file generated by mysql dump. There is one thing left I do not know how to fix properly:

To read the file I use this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader( 
        new InputStreamReader( 
            new FileInputStream( in.toFile() ) ) );

String line;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
{
    buffer.append( line );
    buffer.append( System.lineSeparator() );

    //here goes more code
}
```

The first ugly thing happens by using `buffer.append( System.lineSeparator() );` but that is not overall problem, which looks like this: I wrote a test that compares the input- and output-file (generated by my program) line by line, if lines are not equal (compared via `line1.equals( line2 );`) they are printed out on the console. On the image below the upper line is the original one and the lower one the copied.

[image: console out]

As one can see, there is no noticeable difference. The failure happens only on lines where binary data is inserted, but not on each of them.

So my question:
How can I securely read and write those lines? I also need to access the content of the file as a String to run some regexes against it, so copying byte by byte is not an option, or at least I do not know how to code it.

Thanks in advance…

**Edit**

Well I thought that reading the file was the only reason for the failures, but as it turned out, I guess it is also the writing.

I replaced the code for reading as suggested by Henry to:

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream( in.toFile() );
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
int byteLength;

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while( ( byteLength = inStream.read( byteBuffer ) ) > 0 )
{
    buffer.append( new String( byteBuffer, "UTF-8" ) );
    //more code here
}
```

As a result, the comparison errors still happens, but on different lines. To write the new File I use this code:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( 
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream( out.toFile() ), 
                                   Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) ) );

//while reading
writer.write( buffer.toString() );

//after reading
writer.close();
```

what results in this file:

[image: error writing]

As one can imaging, the first two lines are correct and the rest of the file seems to be the error. How can I fix that, or in other words: Read an UFT-8 encoded File and Write it as UTF-8 encoded File?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is binary content, read the file as bytes and not as characters. This means, don't use a `Reader` but an `InputStream` instead.

When you convert the bytes to text, you will get errors whenever a byte sequence is not a correct character encoding.

Maybe something like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream( in.toFile() );
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf,0,len);
}
```

Comment: that sounds good, but could you probably provide me with some sample code?

Comment: That's correct. InputStreamReader as used by philipp uses the default charset of the system, which can be different to the charset of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer brought me on the right way. My working solution uses a char[] and a reader. The key to solve the encoding problem was connected to the CharsetDecoder/CharsetEncoder…